# Qt5 Android maximized application

Tags: android, qt

When you create a default QML application with the Qt SDK for Android your application always starts as small window. Normally a showExpanded or showFullscreen helps but this results in a black screen. The only way to work around is to use setGeometry with a fixed size, but this not very useful for supporting the big variety of Android devices. I somewhere found someone mentioning that the geometry is not correctly recognized by QML at startup and needs to be manually updated using the QDesktopWidget. Here the quote:

> Application starts in “window” mode (with top panel)
>   At start Qt components gets wrong screen size
>   After load Qt gets correct screen size but QML not
>   How to get correct screen size:
>   Connect to signal QDesktopWidget::workAreaResized()
>   Send to QML new screen size from
>   QDesktopWidget::screenGeometry()

Has someone aleady experienced similar poblems? Btw. I use a splashscreen at startup but I had no poblem with the old Necessitas and on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on qml apps on android devices.

```
include <QGuiApplication>
include <QtQml/QQmlApplicationEngine>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
return app.exec();
}
```

(this is my main.cpp)
and my main.qml is:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
id: mainWin
visible: true
...
...
```

with the above code my app fits full screen on android and i can get the screen size with mainWin.width and mainWin.height.